# Converting decimalized minutes to HH:MM:SS

Tags: php, datetime

I am trying to convert decimalized minutes (i.e. 0.8) to HH:MM:SS format in PHP. I would expect "0.8" to be formatted as "00:00:48". Below is the current code I have, but it is currently generating an error.

```
$decimalized_minutes = "0.8";

$duration = fmod($decimalized_minutes, 60);
$sec = $duration % 60;
$min = fmod(($duration - $sec) / 60, 60);
$hour = ($duration - 60 * $min - $sec) / 3600;
$durDate = new DateInterval("PT$hour" . "H$min" . "M$sec" . 'S');
$returnString = $durDate->format('%H:%I:%S');

echo $returnString;
```

However, I am currently receiving this error:

```
DateInterval::__construct(): Unknown or bad format (PT0H0.013333333333333M0S)
```

Does anyone know what this error means and why I am receiving it? Or perhaps can recommend a library to perform this function?

Comment: Error message is pretty self explanatory?

Comment: What do you think `fmod()` does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert minutes into seconds then use `gmdate("H:i:s", time_in_seconds); //in your case 48`